# Text Justify in react native

Tags: react-native

How can we justify text in react native for both android and iOS without using webView, since webView is not visible in android after placing it inside another view.

The following option only works for iOS.

```
textAlign='justify'
```

Answer (score 1):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style

As it s written here, justify for android is not available... Most of the tricks suggest to use `left` or then a webview as you said...

Comment: Could you give more information about the "left" method? Haven't seen it.

Answer (score -1):

Using webView resolved the issue. To show webView inside the ScrollView I just had to add height to webView.

https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview/issues/7